# Saving parts of a sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Some of my features in a model can take some time to generate, so to experiment with multiple features and parameters quickly it's a good idea to save these to disk for later use.

As a concrete example (taken from [here](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html)), suppose I have the following pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
  ('extract_essays', EssayExractor()),
  ('features', FeatureUnion([
    ('ngram_tf_idf', Pipeline([
      ('counts', CountVectorizer()),
      ('tf_idf', TfidfTransformer())
    ])),
    ('essay_length', LengthTransformer()),
    ('misspellings', MispellingCountTransformer())
  ])),
  ('classifier', MultinomialNB())
])
```

And I would like to change `CountVectorizer()` to `CountVectorizer(max_features=1000)`, then only `CountVectorizer`, `MultinomialNB` need to be recomputed since the parameter or the transform before it has changed.

Can this be implemented somehow?

Comment: Are you asking how to use a tuning grid when training your pipeline or how to adjust a parameter in already trained pipeline object?

Comment: Scikit-learn does not provide a built-in solution, the issue of caching intermediary steps in a pipeline is discussed in two github issues: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2086 and https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3951.

Comment: @user3914041 Thanks for the references. It appears that in my first attempt I have redone parts of `Memory.cache`, so it has already come in handy in avoiding duplicated work.

Comment: how about using GridSearchCV.best_estimator_.get_params() ? are you familiar with that? it might be a partial solution to your problem as you can save the best estimators for the components of your pipeline. later when you are running your code again, just load these parameters and create the pipeline. This way you dont have to tune everytime.

Comment: consider my answer to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353228/feature-selection-using-logistic-regression/33422387#33422387

Comment: is this something related to what you are looking for?

Comment: @AbtPst Not exactly, the issue I'm having is to not retrain parameters if the init parameters and training sets are the same. Your linked question is more about searching for hyperparameters. I've solved my original problem actually by some modifications to https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2086, perhaps I should post an answer some time.

Comment: cool! i will read up more on this

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success doing this sort of thing with [Pachyderm](https://github.com/pachyderm/pachyderm).  It has a somewhat git-like cli that will let you store your workflow.  In the repo, take note of the [ML pipeline for Iris Classification](https://github.com/pachyderm/pachyderm/tree/master/doc/examples/ml/iris) example which gives some details around how to create and save your pipeline & training data into what they call an "inference pipeline" that will allow the kinds of transformations you're attempting and apply the inferred pipeline training data.