# feature selection using logistic regression

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I am performing feature selection ( on a dataset with 1,930,388 rows and 88 features) using Logistic Regression. If I test the model on held-out data, the accuracy is just above 60%. The response variable is equally distributed. My question is, if the model's performance is not good, can I consider the features that it gives as actual important features? Or should I try to improve the accuracy of the model though my end-goal is not to improve the accuracy but only get important features

Comment: what is your feature selector?

Answer (score 0):

sklearn's GridSearchCV has some pretty neat methods to give you the best feature set. For example, consider the following code

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',sublinear_tf=True)),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
    ])

    parameters = {
        'vect__max_df': (0.25, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0),
        'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2), (2,3), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)),
        'vect__use_idf': (True, False),
        'clf__C': (0.1, 1, 10, 20, 30)
    }
```

here the parameters array holds all of the different parameters that i need to consider. notice the use if vect__max_df. max_df is an actual key that is used by my vectorizer, which is my feature selector. So,

```
'vect__max_df': (0.25, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0),
```

actually specifies that i want to try out the above 5 values for my vectorizer. Similarly for the others. Notice how i have tied my vectorizer to the key 'vect' and my classifier to the key 'clf'. Can you see the pattern? Moving on

```
    traindf = pd.read_json('../../data/train.json')

    traindf['ingredients_clean_string'] = [' , '.join(z).strip() for z in traindf['ingredients']]  

    traindf['ingredients_string'] = [' '.join([WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', line)) for line in lists]).strip() for lists in traindf['ingredients']]       

    X, y = traindf['ingredients_string'], traindf['cuisine'].as_matrix()

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7)

    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=3, verbose=1, scoring='accuracy')
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print ('best score: %0.3f' % grid_search.best_score_)
    print ('best parameters set:')

    bestParameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()

    for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print ('\t %s: %r' % (param_name, bestParameters[param_name]))

    predictions = grid_search.predict(X_test)
    print ('Accuracy:', accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
    print ('Confusion Matrix:', confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions))
    print ('Classification Report:', classification_report(y_test, predictions))
```

note that the bestParameters  array will give me the best set of parameters out of all the options that i specified while creating my pipeline.

Hope this helps.

**Edit: To get a list of features selected**

so once you have your best set of parameters, create vectorizers and classifiers with those parameter values

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer('''use the best parameters here''')
```

then you basically train this vectorizer again. in doing so, the vectorizer will choose certain features from your training set.

```
traindf = pd.read_json('../../data/train.json')

        traindf['ingredients_clean_string'] = [' , '.join(z).strip() for z in traindf['ingredients']]  

        traindf['ingredients_string'] = [' '.join([WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', line)) for line in lists]).strip() for lists in traindf['ingredients']]       

        X, y = traindf['ingredients_string'], traindf['cuisine'].as_matrix()

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7)

       termDocMatrix = vect.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

now, the termDocMatrix has all of the selected features. also, you can use the vectorizer to get the feature names. lets say you want to get the top 100 features. and your metric for comparison is the chi square score

```
getKbest = SelectKBest(chi2, k = 100)
```

now just

```
print(np.asarray(vect.get_feature_names())[getKbest.get_support()])
```

should give you the top 100 features. try this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of GridSearch. But that doesn't answer my question. My question was, if I am using any algorithm for feature selection purpose, should I concentrate on the accuracy of the model a lot? For eg, sk learn feature selection methods (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) list random forest, logistic regression etc as standard approaches. How do I choose between the two model based feature selection methods? select on the basis of accuracy?

Comment: accuracy is a good measure, but you should also look at other parameters like ROC curve, precision, recall and f measure. depending on the problem you are trying to solve, one or more of these parameters might be important. thats why it helps creating pipelines so you can compare different models. accuracy is the most straightforward one. by the way, which problem are you trying to solve? what is your use case?

Comment: also, when you say 'end-goal is not to improve the accuracy but only get important features' are you actually looking to get the features that the best performing model selects? i.e. do you want to find out the 'things' that the best performing model is looking at?

Comment: This is my use case : My response variable is binary. My features are numerical( They are certain product features and the attribute values are the number of times a user uses those attributes) I want to find those features which influence the response variable to be 1. I don't intend to classify a user as 1 or 0 in the future. I'm doing the classification only for the important features the model returns.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is a term document matrix. please see my edited answer

Comment: I haven't tried implementing what you suggested, but a quick eye-balling tells me that all of it is related to text-analysis. Mine is not a text analysis problem

Comment: i have just used TfidfVectorizer as an example. you would be able to use these functions with whatever feature selector you use.